# Drawing Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

What does it actually mean when we draw a number from a given distribution?

To elaborate on what exactly I'm trying to ask: if I generate a vector of numbers from the standard normal distribution on a computer, what I get is a bunch of numbers that are fixed afterwards. Yet, can I consider them to be Gaussian? Can I take the norm and consider the result to be drawn from the Chi distribution, as I would if they were 'true' random variables?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In modern probability, a random variable is thought of as a function $X:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$. $X$ may have a known distribution like a Gaussian distribution (this means intuitively if you plot all the values in a histogram it will look like a bell curve). Drawing a number from the distribution means to take a random variable with this distribution and evaluating it at a point $X(\omega)$, $\omega\in\Omega$.

A bunch of numbers drawn from a Gaussian random variable will not be Gaussian distributed themselves, but will approximate it and approach the distribution of the random variable they are drawn from as the number of draws approaches $\infty$.

The sum of squares of values drawn from a Gaussian random variable will be distributed like a chi-squared random variable, so that's a yes to your second question.